# curl_multi_exec returning blanks sometimes

Tags: php, curl

Basically there are a couple hundred subpages I'm pulling off a site (as a test run), and then I have to parse each of those couple hundred subpages for some data.  Now all this is working and fine.  But of course, it takes too long because there are so many pages, if I did this in serial.  So I used curl_multi_exec, but now I'm running into the problem where some of those pages will return blank.  Which pages are blank is quite random so I'm assuming it has to do with the web server deciding not to respond given that I'm spamming it with 200 requests at once.  Is there a way to either limit the number of requests at once or have curl redo the request if it didn't return properly, or otherwise deal with this problem?

Existing curl code:

```
function multiple_html_requests($nodes){
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $curl_array = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $i=>$url){
        $curl_array[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl_array[$i]);
    }
    $running = NULL;
    do{
      usleep(10000);
      curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while($running > 0);

    $res = array();
    foreach($nodes as $i=>$url){
        $res[$url] = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_array[$i]);
    }

    foreach($nodes as $i=>$url){
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $curl_array[$i]);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: You could start by using `curl_getinfo()` on the individual requests or `curl_multi_info_read()` on `$mh` to keep track of which requests failed, then try them again after the do-while loop.

The error codes found in the returned info might give you more info as to exactly why they are failing as well, and you might be able to fix that problem directly.

Comment: Well basically the server returns a default error page, which I guess I could parse for errors and keep retrying if that happened.  Not sure if that's the best way of doing vs just limiting how many are going on in parallel as well.  By the way, what would be a near fastest speed about 200 pages could be loaded and parsed in?  I'm hitting about ~20 seconds per run on average, not sure if that's slow or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this class:

```
https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl
```

Is a layer over curl multi and support setting maximum number of threads